# Як правильно перекласти з англійської - wire frame drawing?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни, словосполучення

Питання стосується комп'ютерної графіки.

Перекладаю це речення:

> Цей метод (рейтрейсінг) споживає дуже багато часу, як правило, для
>   корисних результатів потрібно кілька тисяч секунд, так багато
>   розрахунків, як і в **wire frame drawing**.

Comment: [Використовуй силу, Люку...](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Трішки не за темою, але: за [правилом дев'ятки](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Правило_дев'ятки) мало б бути «рейтрейс**и**нг». Іще: дуже дивно, що в ньому «потрібно <…> так багато розрахунків, як і в wire frame drawing»; в wire frame drawing насправді **не**багато розрахунків, а в ray tracing — в кілька тисяч разів **більше**, ніж в wire frame.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ми можемо малювати заповнені багатокутники або лише їхні ребра.

[image]

Хоча *Загальний народний англійсько-український словник* має статтю [wireframe](http://e2u.org.ua/s?w=wireframe&dicts=all&highlight=on)

> **wireframe** [ˈwʌɪəfreɪm] *n*
>       1) каркас; каркасне предста́влення
>       2) *комп*. функціональний макет
>       • wire frame model — каркасна модель
>       • website wireframe — макет вебсайту

але переклад *каркасне малювання* чи *малювання каркасу* мені не дуже подобається. Якось зрозуміліше звучить *малювання ребер* для *wireframe drawing* і *малювання граней* для *solid drawing*.

Answer (score 3):

Підтримуючи [відповідь Yola](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/1278/4), все ж хотів би сказати на захист терміна «каркасна модель», що:

- Є [відповідна стаття](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C) у Вікіпедії.
- Цей термін вживається [в російських книжках](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%22) з комп'ютерної графіки, а також в деяких українських матеріалах:

  - > *Каркасна модель являє собою скелетний опис 3D об'єкту, що складається з відрізків і кривих.* //[«Електронний посібник з дисципліни: Системи 3D моделювання» (Луцький національний технічний університет, Технологічний факультет, Кафедра ПАВП; Луцьк – 2013)](http://pavp.in.ua/docs/enp/s3dm/page27.html).
  - > *Для формування об'ємних зображень використовуються каркасний, контурний і напівтоновий методи. У каркасних конструкціях (рис. 4.11) видимими є всі лінії конструкції. <…> Рис. 4.11. Каркасна модель.* //[Романюк О. Н. «Комп'ютерна графіка» (Віницький національний технічний університет)](http://posibnyky.vntu.edu.ua/k_g/zmg1/zmg/45.htm).
  - > *Суть каркасної моделі в тому, що об’єкт розрізається сукупністю паралельних площин, які у свою чергу паралельні певній базовій площині.* //[Цибенко Б. О. «Методичні вказівки до виконання курсової роботи з дисципліни „Мови об’єктно-орієнтованого програмування“. Випуск 189» (Чорноморський державний університет імені Петра Могили, 2012; УДК 004.43 (076), ББК 73я7, 
    >   ISSN 1811-492X)](http://lib.chdu.edu.ua/pdf/metodser/190/7.pdf).
- Цей термін є навіть в словнику:

  > м. каркасная — модель каркасна //[Роман Кінаш «Русско-украинский и украинско-русский словарь терминов строительства и архитертуры в двух томах: том I, русско-украинский словарь» (2005, Ліга-Прес)](//books.google.com/books?id=lKIoAQAAIAAJ&dq=%22%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C+%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B0%22).

  Але не факт, що саме в цьому значенні.